# why the NFS v3 is stateless and NFS V4 is state full?

Tags: filesystems, nfs

is there any specific reason why the authors chosen NFS v3 as stateless and V4 as state full?

Answer (score 1):

NFS V4 is explicitly stateful, in contrast with earlier versions of NFS, which are stateless in principle, but rely on an auxiliary stateful protocol (NLM) for file locking. Among other things, this means that file locking operations are part of the NFS4 protocol proper, eliminating the need for separate rpc.statd and rpc.lockd daemons.